# React chakra-ui is centering the all layout

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying create a react app with chackra-ui but when I add chakra to project its centers  all layout. I can't make the width property 100. Chakra is breaking something or my config is wrong.

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
 document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
  <ChakraProvider>
    <App />
  </ChakraProvider>
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import RootLayout from "./layout/RootLayout";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
 {
   path: "/",
   element: <RootLayout />,
 },
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
  }

 export default App;
```

RootLayout.tsx(This is my container component. I added some css for crush the chakras container css.)

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Image, Flex } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import background from "../public/img/town.png";

import Main from "../components/Main";

export default function test() {
  const mainContainerCss = {
    background:
      "linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,212,255,0.3) 62%, rgba(150,75,0,1) 100%)",
    minHeight: "100vh",
    position: "relative",
    h: "100%",
    width: "100%", // I add for fix the problem
    margin: "0 !important", // I add for fix the problem
    padding: "0 !important", // I add for fix the problem
    minWidth: "100%" // I add for fix the problem
  };

  const backgroundImageCss = {
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    bottom: "0",
  };
  return (
    <Container as="main" sx={mainContainerCss}>
      <Image sx={backgroundImageCss} src={background} alt="Pollygon" />
      <Flex flexDirection="column" h="100%">
        <Main />
      </Flex>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

[image]

First container have much margin via chakra.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ChakraProvider` does inject some global styles. It uses a CSS reset (variation of [this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)). CSS resets are usually good, and to be honest it could be worth you altering the styles of your page to be compatible with the reset rather than turning it off. [This](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/css-reset/src/css-reset.tsx) is Chakras reset.

Alternatively (and you might want to do this at least temporarily, or permanently if you decide you don't care about the reset, to figure out if it's the problem) you could disable it by setting the `resetCSS` prop to `false`.

If this is the problem it's up to you whether the gains of the reset are worth it for you. If you had loads of existing pages already styled in a certain way and there was a clear significant negative impact in lots of places it probably wouldn't be worth the effort and you could turn it off.

More info on [resets available here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/).

```
<ChakraProvider resetCSS={false}>
```

By the way, we could give better advice if you posted the component that does not display correctly, alongside its associated styles.

Comment: Firstly, thank you  for the answer. I tried close the reset CSS but it's doesn't solve it. Actually I don't have much css right now. It solves the problem when I reset the margin padding of the first container and give the width property 100. I think  first css  is broken my container. I am sharing the other components.